# iOS Simple SQLite Select Statement in Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, select, swift

I plan on updating an old application which is currently using a SQLITE database.

My new application is written in iOS8/Swift.

Is there an easy way to run a select statement on SQLite database file and iterate through the results? While doing this I'll be transferring the information into a new Core Data database.

eg: select id, someDate, someString, someInt from myTable;

After I've performed this select statement I will never do anything else with SQLite so i'm not looking at adding anything major to the application. Just a very quick select to grab seeding data.

Hope this makes sense. I'm just confused when trying to do this in Swift.

====== UPDATE ======

I'm going with SQLite.swift. Easy to setup and get running.

The following is working but am I correctly checking if the values are NOT NIL? Is this the best way to check?

```
let stmt = db.prepare("SELECT anID, aString FROM someTable")
for row in stmt {

    if var myID:Int = row[0] as Int? {  // do something here if exists  }
    if var myString:String = row[1] as String? {  // do something here if exists  }

}
```

Comment: You can simplify a bit by only declaring the type once, and I believe you meant to use `let` to unwrap, _e.g._, `if let myID = row[0] as Int? { /* ... */ }`. (Also, the second should be `row[1]`.)

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. The [2] was a copy paste mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), but it's definitely living in the Objective-C ages. I wrote [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to work better with the Swift programming language.

Your example above would most simply look like this:

```
let stmt = db.prepare("SELECT id, someDate, someString, someInt FROM myTable")
for row in stmt {
    // [Optional(1), Optional("2014-10-30"), Optional("Hello!"), Optional(5)]
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you. I've updated my original question for further clarification on the best way to check if values are Nil.

Comment: Replied. By default there's no way to guarantee at compile time that a column value will never be `NULL`, so optionals are the way to go, and your decision to use `if`–`let` is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

`FMDB` is an amazing third party library that interfaces with `sqlite`.

A detailed `swift` `FMDB` tutorial can be found [here](http://metrozines.com/)